# Knockout click on checkbox can't define new check box state in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

I have next checkbox on my page and

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbSelectAll" data-bind="click:modelAddrView.selectAllOnPage">
```

And I have  function in my model that define new checkbox state and  make some operation but my method how I define state is not working in IE `( $(event.toElement).is(':checked') return false )`.

```
self.selectAllOnPage = function (data, event) {
    var list = self.pageDataView();
    var operationSet = $(event.toElement).is(':checked');
    self.selectArray(list, operationSet);
    $("#addrList input:checkbox").attr("checked", $(event.toElement).is(':checked'));
    //self.selected(list);
    return true;
}
```

How to define new check box state in correct way with Knockout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have findout issue I need use $(event.target)

Answer (score 0):

I would also change your .attr to .prop  I had several issues with check and radio buttons that was directly related to the depreciation of .attr

Comment: this is selection on some other checkboxex